# Как тестируется Flash?

Tags: flash, тестирование

Какими методами, способами и т.д. тестируется Flash? Как его тестировать вручную, как тестировать автоматически? Какие применяются инструменты для автоматического тестирования?

Comment: Одно из важных утечек это нагрузка на браузер.

Comment: Flashbug ?..

Answer (score 1):

Для отладки вам понадобится [flash player debug](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html). Прочитайте документацию к нему.

Как подключать к средам разработки должно быть в документациях самих IDE. Смотря что вы используете из IDE для flash:

- Adobe Flash Pro (Flash IDE)
- Adobe Flash Builder
- FlashDevelop
- IntelliJ IDEA